# which jar contains org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap in spring2.5?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using spring2.5. and trying to implement a custom CommonsMultipartResolver for ajax upload.

After I submited form, I got following error:

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletExceptio n: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsF ileUploadSupport$MultipartParsingResult.getMultipa rtFiles()Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;

It seems that I need class org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap. But I can not find it anywhere in spring2.5.

Can you tell me which jar contains it?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It supposed to be in  org.springframework.core...jar file, but such class does not exist in Spring 2.5

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.0/api/org/springframework/util/package-summary.html

It was added only in Spring 3.0.x

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/package-tree.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be mixing versions of spring jars, since the 2.5 version returns a regular `Map` as parameters to the `getMultiPartFiles()` method ([javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsFileUploadSupport.MultipartParsingResult.html)). The 3.0.x version uses `MultiValueMap` ([javadoc](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsFileUploadSupport.MultipartParsingResult.html)).

It's not the map type that is missing, but the method. Check that you are using spring-web version that matches the rest of your spring dependencies.